# Moving from air traffic modelling to swarm intelligences

Tags: soft-question

Having recently taken up a research role in a research institute within a University where I work alongside Postdocs, professors, regulators and the aerospace industries, I have been contemplating on exit opportunities in the near future.
An area of interest of mine could be in swarm intelligence.

My background is in physics and mathematics at the undergraduate level.
How feasible is the move into swarm intelligence using mathematical and physics-based models?